# How do I give users reboot rights on fedora?

Tags: fedora, user-management, sudo

On a fedora server, an web application which is in development stages, get stoked for unknown reasons for the moment. The only solution is to restart the linux machine, but only the root has acces to do that.

Is it possible to give reboot rights to a user group? Can you give me some ideas about how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use sudo to do this

as root use the "visudo" commmand to edit the /etc/sudoers file

If you want to allow a group of users access to reboot the computer you can add the following line:

```
%shutdowngroup ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

(Where "shutdowngroup" is the name of the group that users would need to be a member of)

If you want to grant one use at a time you can add the following line:

```
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give root privileges using sudoers file. You can specify the command and username/groupname.

To edit this file, you can use: `sudo visudo`

For more info, see `man visudo` and `man sudoers`.